# JSTL EL parameters auto supplement?

Tags: jstl, el

I've come across a strange problem, in my old code

```
${fn:substring(value, 13)}
```

can work OK. But after we upgrade to Websphere7, it complains

```
Unable to parse el function ${fn:substring(value, 13)}
```

If we supply the third parameter, it works

```
${fn:substring(value, 13, 0)}
```

I checked the standard.jar the version is correct and I do find the `tld` inside jar only serve the 3-parameters version of `substring`. This leads me to think that is that some older version EL will auto supply the third parameter if not found? Any where I can find this info?

Comment: You've upgraded to WebSphere7 from which app server?

Comment: I'm supporting the answer from BalusC, the only possible reasons why this works must be either a bug on your old server or a very old JSTL library on your server, which might have resided in your old ...server/lib directory.

Answer (score 1):

That was apparently a bug in your old server.

The [official docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/fn/substring.fn.html) says that it must take 3 arguments.

> #### Function substring
>
> `java.lang.String substring(java.lang.String, int, int)`

Fix your code accordingly to be not dependent on the bug of your old server anymore.

#### See also:

- [Index of all JSTL tag/function documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/)